# this.contract.deployed() is not a function

Tags: dapp-development, truffle-contract, react

I'm working on making a React frontend for my smart contract, but I'm having problems connecting it into my React code.

Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```js
import TruffleContract from 'truffle-contract'

...

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Initialize MetaMask plugin
    this.web3 = new Web3();
    const isMetaMaskEnabled = () => !!window.web3;

    if (!isMetaMaskEnabled()) {
      alert('Add the Metamask pluging to your browser to continue');
      return;
    }

    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      try {
        // Request account access if needed
        window.ethereum.enable().then(() => {
          console.log("Accounts now exposed")
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      } catch(error) {
        // User denied account access
        console.log(error).then(() => {
          console.log("unable to obtain MetaMask Account")
        })
      }
    } else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider).then(() => {
        console.log("Accounts always exposed")
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    } else {
      console.log("Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!")
    }

    this.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
    .then(function(netID) {
      while (netID !== 'main') {
        // alert('Select Main Ethereum Network in MetaMask')
      }
    });

    this.state = {
      ...
      uAddress: '0x0'
    }

    this.users = TruffleContract(Users);
    this.users.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider)

    this.users = this.users.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.users.deployed().then((instance) => {
      this.setState( {uAddress: instance.address} )
    })
  }
```

When I try to call deployed() on this.users, I'm getting the error,

```
TypeError: this.users.deployed is not a function
```

I know there have been similar questions asked, but they create a contract instance using the abi and contract address, and not using the TruffleContract method. I want to know if it's possible to get this way to work.

Comment: Why would you need ``this.users = this.users.bind(this)``?

Comment: I'm planning on passing it into a child component. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @JarethRader Normally `.bind()` is used for functions not objects.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but it's working now. And I did remove `this.users = this.users.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes here looking for an answer, I've figured it out.

I changed how I instance my contract. I create a separate js file to store an object with all the contract data;

```js
module.exports = {
  address: "(Your-Contract-Address-Goes_here)",
  abi: [
    {
     (Your-Contract-ABI-goes-here)
    }
  ]
}
```

then to create the instance, I get Web3 and use the web3.eth.Contract method;

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/(You-Infura-Secret-Goes-Here)"
  )
);

const Contract = require("Path-To-Contract");
const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  Contract.abi,
  Contract.address
);
```

Now you should be able to make calls to your contract using the web3 api like so,

```js
let data = contract.method.Contract_Method.call(Any-Varibles-Go-Here).encodeABI();
web3.eth.sendTransaction(data [,callback]);
```

Sending write methods is a little different, and using Infura will also actually require you to sign your own transaction and use `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()` but I won't elaborate on that here. If you're using Metamask, or I assume Dapper although I haven't tried it, it will work the way I have explained about. Metamask will sign transactions you send on their own nodes I believe which is why this works, but Infura will not sign transactions on their nodes.